# GetElementByClassName and regexp

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have `div` with `class` and `id` attributes in document like this:

```
<div class="blabla11" id="bla22">
```

In the class and id values *blabla* is constant while digits are not. How can I get the elements by class **and** by id if some parts of the class and div names are generated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the divs, and use regex to test

```
var selected = [];
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(/^blabla/.test(divs[i].className)) {
        // selected.push(divs[i]);
        divs[i].parentNode.removeChild(divs[i]); // try this to remove
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1503172 you can thank me by clicking on the hollow "V" sign to the left of my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can use this selector:

```
$('div[class^="blabla"][id^="bla"]')
```

Where:

- the class^="blabla" matches all the class values starting with "blabla" string.
- the [...][...] concatenation matches both conditions.

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for further details.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AUTJ4/22/).

Comment: Please add a comment besides your downvotes. Thanks.